# transform on canvas causes strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I played around with the canvas element and the following code works fine without the transform but when I put the transform in, the red box draws a "tail" behind itself. Strangely the color of that tail is different than that of the box and it is also different from browser to browser (much darker in FF).
Is that normal? I guess it's due to rounding.

```
function draw() {  
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 g = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var x = 0;
 var y = 200;
 g.transform(.5,0,0,1,0,0);
 g.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
 timer = setInterval(function() {
     if(x == 750) clearInterval(timer);
     g.clearRect(x,y,50,50);
     x ++;
     g.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
     g.fillRect(x,y,50,50);
 }, 10);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
 <head>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
 </head>  
 <body onload="draw()">
   <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: btw. transform(.5,0,0,1,0,0) is the same as scale(0.5,1). Try scale(0.99,1) to get in interesting effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the scaling is being applyed to the `clearRect` as well. At every call to the `setInterval` callback function the last drawn rect is being perfectly covered by the `clearRect` with a white color since the X value is still the same, but when you call the `fillRect` in order to draw the red rect again the X value is incremented by 1. Since your X axis is scaled by .5 (half a pixel), at even values it takes another pixel but on odd values it is supposed to take "half a pixel", since that doesn't exist the two colors of the pixels (white and red) are blended to try to get a smooth-ish effect since both colors are supposed to be on that pixel taking half of the pixel each. Which I guess is good most of the time but in this case for example it is not.

```
So let x be 2 (forget about the y axis here, kay?)
Have a rect from x to x+50 (transformed coords are 1, 26)
Clear rect from x to x+50 (1, 26)

We end up here with a white rect from 1 to 26, right?

add 1 to x
Have a rect from x to x+50 (1.5, 26.5)

Oops, there's no such pixel 1.5, 1 it is.
Pixel one is filled with white already, nobody ordered me to clear that but I have to fill with red this same pixel.

Solution = blend colors
```

Yeah, so the tail you see is the result of 1 column of pixels that are filled with the red+white, not fully white to desapear nor fully red to mix with the rest of the rect.

A solution would be:

```
g.clearRect(x-1,y,50,50);
```

Using `x-1` you'll be able to catch this column of pixels.

Hope I was clear.

The difference on the tone I supposed is due to the differences in the implementation of the blending in each browser, maybe, but I've always noticed some differences in the tones of the same color depending on the browser, not only on canvas apps.